# How do I get autoconf to find and use the correct version of a program when multiple versions are installed on an operating system?

Tags: autotools, autoconf, automake

I'm trying to modify an existing configure.ac file. I want to compile some software on a FreeBSD system. The base system includes binutils 2.17.5, but I also have the newer binutils 2.33.1 installed from ports. As such, there are multiple versions of the same software on the system. I want autoconf to use the assembler located at /usr/local/bin/as which is the 2.33.1 version, but currently it finds and uses the one at /usr/bin/as which is the old 2.17.5 version. As a result, the software fails to compile.

Since a user could be running autoconf on Linux, FreeBSD, or another OS, the configuration phase needs to be flexible enough to find the correct version of as regardless of operating system -- not just the FreeBSD system I'm working on.

The current snippet of code is

```
AC_CHECK_PROGS([AS], [i386-elf-as as])
if test -z "$AS"; then
  AC_MSG_ERROR(as not found)
fi
```

How could I modify this configure.as file to achieve the results I'm looking for?

Answer (score 2):

`AC_CHECK_PROGS` does exactly what [its docs](https://www.gnu.org/software/autoconf/manual/autoconf-2.69/html_node/Generic-Programs.html) say it does: it looks for the specified program names *in the path*.  However, if you want to use a different copy of a tool than the one that a path search would discover then the docs also say

> The result of this test can be overridden by setting the `variable` variable

In other words, if `configure` finds variable `AS` predefined in its environment then it will use that instead of performing a search.  The output of your `configure --help` should even mention AS among the influential environment variables.  This serves as a mechanism for the user to override `configure`'s default choice.

You shouldn't need to modify `configure` at all to achieve that.

Moreover, with regard to

> Since a user could be running autoconf on Linux, FreeBSD, or another
> OS, the configuration phase needs to be flexible enough to find the
> correct version of as regardless of operating system -- not just the
> FreeBSD system I'm working on.

it is rare for there to be multiple versions of tools such as `as` installed on the same system, and building software using non-default tools (as judged with respect to the system's default path) is an expert activity.  As such, I think it would be an exercise in overengineering to go further to attempt to choose a suitable assembler automatically.